# UITableView was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it, Only crash in iOS9, iOS10

Tags: ios, objective-c, key-value-observing

I remove all obsevers when dealloc, but i look crash seems like not remove success, i don't know why, everyone can help me.

this is my code and crash info. i can't figure out what's wrong with my code, anyone who can help me.

```
@interface SYDiagnoseFloatingView()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *imageView;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray<UIScrollView *> *scrollViews;

@end

@implementation SYDiagnoseFloatingView
```

Remove obsevers

```
- (void)dealloc {
    for (UIScrollView *scrollView in self.scrollViews) {
        [scrollView removeObserver:self forKeyPath:keypath];
    }
}
```

Add obsevers

```
- (void)addFloatingTargetView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if ([self.scrollViews containsObject:scrollView]) {
        return;
    }
    [self.scrollViews addObject:scrollView];
    [scrollView addObserver:self forKeyPath:keypath options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];
}
```

Stack trace
 #0 Thread

```
NSInternalInconsistencyException

An instance 0x108d20600 of class UITableView was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Current observation info: <NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x171428ba0> ( <NSKeyValueObservance 0x174a4b370: Observer: 0x1742f8280, Key path: contentOffset, Options: <New: YES, Old: YES, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x17125db50> )

解析原始
0 CoreFoundation    ___exceptionPreprocess + 124
1 libobjc.A.dylib   objc_exception_throw + 56
2 CoreFoundation    -[NSException initWithCoder:]
3 Foundation    _NSKVODeallocate + 300
4 CoreFoundation    _common_removeAllObjects + 188
5 CoreFoundation    -[__NSArrayM dealloc] + 28
6 SoYoungMobile40   -[SYDiagnoseFloatingView .cxx_destruct] (SYDiagnoseFloatingView.m:19)
7 libobjc.A.dylib   0x000000019203c000 + 28432
8 libobjc.A.dylib   objc_destructInstance + 92
9 libobjc.A.dylib   object_dispose + 28
10 UIKit    -[UIResponder dealloc] + 156
11 UIKit    -[UIView dealloc] + 1676
12 SoYoungMobile40  -[SYDiagnoseFloatingView dealloc] (SYDiagnoseFloatingView.m:0)
13 CoreFoundation   _common_removeAllObjects + 188
14 CoreFoundation   -[__NSArrayM dealloc] + 28
15 libobjc.A.dylib  0x000000019203c000 + 139232
16 UIKit    -[UIView dealloc] + 1644
17 libobjc.A.dylib  0x000000019203c000 + 139232
18 UIKit    -[UIView dealloc] + 1644
19 libobjc.A.dylib  0x000000019203c000 + 139232
20 UIKit    -[UIView dealloc] + 1644
21 UIKit    -[UINavigationTransitionView dealloc] + 100
22 libobjc.A.dylib  0x000000019203c000 + 139232
23 UIKit    -[UIView dealloc] + 1644
24 UIKit    -[UILayoutContainerView dealloc] + 64
25 libobjc.A.dylib  0x000000019203c000 + 139232
26 UIKit    -[UIView dealloc] + 1644
27 libobjc.A.dylib  0x000000019203c000 + 139232
28 CoreFoundation   _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 28
29 CoreFoundation   ___CFRunLoopRun + 1668
30 CoreFoundation   CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
31 GraphicsServices GSEventRunModal + 180
32 UIKit    -[UIApplication _run] + 684
33 UIKit    UIApplicationMain + 208
34 SoYoungMobile40  main (main.m:16)
35 libdyld.dylib    _start + 4
```

Comment: How do you add observers?

Comment: I have add the code to the question please review

Comment: Where do you call `addFloatingTargetView:`?

Comment: in main thread call

Comment: But maybe you call it twice. Have you tried the code from my answer?

Comment: Thanks, Another Manger Observer the UIScrollView too, But the Manager weak the UIScrollView, when UIScrollView Dealloc, the Manager still KVO the UIScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

I think you add the same observer twice. Always call `[scrollView removeObserver:self forKeyPath:keypath context:nil]`; before `[scrollView addObserver:self forKeyPath:keypath options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];`.

Comment: Yes, Thanks, Another Manager Still KVO the scrollView, but Another Manage weak the scrollView

Comment: @Chendichuan And now you don't get an exception, right?